# React-Native-Image-Picker ( cannot map array of images )

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Now I meet some problem as I try to customize my app when the user select or take image it will save in state as an array, but when I try to map it back in view it doesn't show anything.

Here some of my code:

```
state = {
    imageSource: []
};
```

this is how i set my state:

```
this.setState({
  imageSource: this.state.imageSource.concat(source) 
});
```

here is my view function:

```
viewImages(){

      this.state.imageSource.map(function(image){
      console.log(image);
        return(
          <View style={[styles.image, styles.imageContainer, {marginBottom: 20}]}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
          </View>
        )
      });

  }
```

and this is my render view

```
<View style={styles.containerImage}>
          {this.viewImages()}
</View
```

and finally here is my console log that I have got from view Function above:

```
Object {uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-e23b89ed-83b9-4e10-8912-c96e87aab6f0.jpg", isStatic: true}
Object {uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-473d8554-2f53-4870-b94e-03306a17f6e6.jpg", isStatic: true}
```

Whre did I go wrong! 
Thank.

Comment: What is the output of the program? Are you getting any error string?

Comment: `<image key={uri} style=...`   I'm still learning this stuff too.... could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `return`.

```
 return this.state.imageSource.map(function(image){
```

Looks like you're throwing away the map.